# Missing mutant-rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, rake, bundler

I'm trying to set up a new Ruby project on a newly installed Debian 8.5 using the `ruby 2.1.5+deb8u2` an `ruby-dev 2.1.5+deb8u2` packages from the repository. I want to include mutation testing in my project. I added `mutant-rspec` to my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake'
gem 'rspec', require: 'spec'
gem 'mutant-rspec'
```

Bundler (1.13.0) seems to install the gem just fine

```
ytg@debian-vm:~/projects/new_project$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Using rake 11.2.2
....
Using rspec-core 3.5.3
Using rspec-expectations 3.5.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.5.0
...
Using rspec 3.5.0
...
Installing mutant 0.8.11
Installing mutant-rspec 0.8.11
Bundle complete! 5 Gemfile dependencies, 34 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Now if I try to run mutant, using `rake mutant --trace` with the rake file

```
require 'bundler/gem_tasks'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
require 'rubocop/rake_task'
require 'mutant'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new :spec

task default: :spec

RuboCop::RakeTask.new

task :mutant do
  result = Mutant::CLI.run %w(--since problem9 -Ilib -Ispec
                              --use rspec MyProject*)
  raise 'Mutation testing failed' unless result
end
```

I get an error message:

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby21, which recognizes
warning: 2.1.8-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.1.5.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
** Invoke mutant (first_time)
** Execute mutant
Could not load integration "rspec" (you may want to try installing the gem mutant-rspec)
rake aborted!
Mutation testing failed
/home/ytg/projects/new_project/Rakefile:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => mutant
```

The same message appears if I try to do it directly

```
ytg@debian-vm:~/projects/new_project$ mutant -I lib/ --use rspec MyProject*
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby21, which recognizes
warning: 2.1.8-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.1.5.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
Could not load integration "rspec" (you may want to try installing the gem mutant-rspec)
```

As I understand this is because of [some loading issue](https://github.com/mbj/mutant/issues/269). But what loading issue exactly? How can I run `mutant` on my project?

(I also tried to install the gem with `sudo gem install mutant-rspec` just in case, but it didn't help, I get the same error message.)

Comment: Have you tried addressing the warning about the 2.1.5 ABI?

Comment: As I understand: 1. Ruby MRI Parser is impossible to be compatible with 2. `parser` would only be used by `mutant` after it successfully starts for the actual analysis of my rb files. So I guess it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It likely won't be a problem at this stage, but it is the only clue at this point, and you probably want to fix that eventually. Anyway, this is an issue with your ruby development environment, but I don't know enough about how you set it up to help troubleshoot.

Comment: I added some info about the environment, otherwise I use the default values everywhere, I didn't hack around the place. (And I would prefer not to, I'm more of a Java guy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mutant` you are running is likely not executing in the right environment. Try `bundle exec mutant` instead, which will ensure the one specified in your `Gemfile` is being used alongside the right set of gems.

To help debug, use `which mutant` to figure out which version is getting called. `sudo gem install` should *not* be a solution, I would recommend `sudo gem uninstall` to revert back to where you were, otherwise it may cause problems later.

But I think all of that is a red herring.

For your `Rakefile`, it isn't actually shelling out to the `mutant` script. You're bypassing it and going direct to `Mutant::CLI`. The problem here is that nothing is setting up the load path so that it would include `mutant-rspec`:

```
task :mutant do
  puts $LOAD_PATH # debug: see it's missing load path for mutant-rspec
  require 'bundler/setup' # This line is new
  puts $LOAD_PATH # debug: see how it changes

  result = Mutant::CLI.run %w(--since problem9 -Ilib -Ispec
                              --use rspec MyProject*)
  raise 'Mutation testing failed' unless result
end
```

Or alternatively, `bundle exec rake mutant` should also do the same thing. I'd recommend *always* using `bundle exec` (or binstubs), rather than whatever `rake` happens to be on your path. Otherwise it's hard to reason about.

Comment: After uninstalling all gems, installing everything with bundler... `bundle exec` seems to do the trick. Now the question is how can I make my rake target use bundle's mutant (`/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mutant-0.8.11/`) instead of the other mutant (`/usr/local/bin/mutant`)? And what is this other mutant anyway?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your `Rakefile` definition? For your second question, try `dlocate /usr/local/bin/mutant` to see if maybe it was installed by a package. Otherwise, `cat /usr/local/bin/mutant` to see if that gives you any clues (maybe install there by a `gem install`?).

Comment: Edited the Rakefile into the question. `dlocate` doesn't give any results. `cat` shows that `# This file was generated by RubyGems.` and it seems to be some rubygems logic for loading the actual mutant gem.

Comment: edited answer, does that fix it? Also and not needed to fix the issue, but try a regular `gem uninstall mutant` to get rid of the `/usr/local` one.

Comment: Your line fixed it for me indeed. Thank you very much. The `$LOAD_PATH` does change meanwhile. The Matcher field shows the entire load path when running from rake, but  guess I can live with that. And uninstalling the gem indeed gets rid of the "other" mutant, but then also bundler stops seeing it, so it gets rid of all the mutants on my system. (Or just the one and its mirage.) Anyway, thanks again.